# aligning the text in a div to the bottom

Tags: html, alignment

I have two divs next to each other, one with `float: right` and the other with `float: left`. The one on the left contains an image (200x100px) and the div on the right should contain a text. I would like to have the text of the div on the right to start on the bottom left of the div instead of the top left, is that possible somehow?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the container `position: relative` then make a div inside with `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;`

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 300px; width: 300px; background-color: #f00;">
  <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background-color: #00f;">
    This will be at the bottom!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css rule on the span, paragraph or whatever you're placing the text in:

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Comment: i think there might be problems in some browsers without display: table

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add to your div this css:

```
 #rightDiv{
   display: table;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```